# How to identify classes names in a String or snippet?

Tags: java

I want to identify all classes names inside a string, example:

```
"...
You can use Runtime.exec(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], 
java.io.File) where you can set the working directory.

Or else you can use ProcessBuilder as follows:

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", 
"myArg2");
pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
Process p = pb.start();
..."
```

In this case, I would like to get: Runtime, String, File, ProcessBuilder and Process. I did my research and found a similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100910/identify-methods-variable-method-calling-in-a-java-piece-of-code). This question has been asked more than 3 years ago, so I thought maybe some new API came up to solve this ? I also realized that [JavaPaser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) and other advanced Parsers will not solve this. For me it is not important if the parsed word is really an API element, ex: the word "process" x the class "Process" because I consider that I can distinguish the semantics through some Machine Learning technique. I really care only about the parsing of the string. I appreciate any help.

Comment: How would this work? Any word in your snippet could potentially be a class. How would I be able to distinguish say `Runtime` vs 'directory' vs 'You`? Any one of those could potentially be a class right?

Comment: That's right, I should check if the token would belong to a class name. Maybe I  get the list of all classes, from all possible packages previously.. any idea where I get those classes names?

Comment: Even if you did that, it doesn't take context into account. E.g., `Process`, above you tagged it as a class but what if someone uses it in a context that doesn't relate it to a class? Would you still mark it as such? I.e. "Process the tests and...". Would you still tag Process in this case as a class even though in the sentence's context, it wasn't used as a Java class?

Comment: In this case I could use some machine learning classifier to tell me if a matched name is really an API element..

Comment: Sure, you could definitely do that or something like that, not saying it is impossible, but you may want to edit your question to include some of these details since that would great increase the complexity and scope of what you are asking.

Comment: You are right. I edited the question.